# How to change joypy joyplot y-axis labels colors

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, joypy

How do you change the colors of the y-axis labels in a joyplot using joypy package?

Here is a sample code where i can change the color if the x-axis labels, but not the y-axis.

```
import joypy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## DATA
url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/iris/iris.data"
new_names = ['SepalLength','SepalWidth','PetalLength','PetalWidth','Name']
iris = pd.read_csv(url, names=new_names, skiprows=0, delimiter=',')

## PLOT
fig, axes = joypy.joyplot(iris)

## X AXIS
plt.tick_params(axis='x', colors='red') 

## Y AXIS     (NOT WORKING)
plt.tick_params(axis='y', colors='red')
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure the issue is because there are mutliple sub-y-axis's, one for each density plot, and they are actually hidden already.
Not sure how to access the y-axis that is actually shown (I want to change the color of "SepalLength")

Joyplot is using Matplotlib

Comment: try hits:`label = axes[0].get_yticklabels();axes[0].set_yticklabels(label, fontdict={'color': 'r'})`

Comment: this is not working

Comment: We have created the code in [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Kfbqv44WxLumdbmvpad8sbN-S0S2Gpym?usp=sharing), please check it.

Comment: The key versions are matplotlib(3.2.2), joypy(0.2.5). Is your environment compatible with this?

Answer (score 0):

r-beginners' comment worked for me. If you want to change the colors of all the y-axis labels, you can iterate through them like this:

```
for ax in axes:
    label = ax.get_yticklabels()
    ax.set_yticklabels(label, fontdict={'color': 'r'})
```

This results in a warning that you're not supposed to use `set_xticklabels()` before fixing the tick positions using `set_xticks` (see documentation [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html)) but with joypy it didn't result in any errors for me.

Here's another solution that just changes the color of the label directly:

```
for ax in axes:
    label = ax.get_yticklabels()
    label[0].set_color('red')
```